# Rerender MUI tree with disabled treeItems

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI TreeView where its treeItems are rendered in a function.
The problem I have is that I want to toggle disable on every treeItem.
But when I try that, the items aren't disabled until I click somewhere.

You could see it in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-raman-rlow3i?file=/demo.tsx)

(When you use the toggle button it seems to work as I expect from the second click and forward, but using the other two you see the problem I have)

```
const Tree = (props: Props) => {

  const handleToggle = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, nodeIds: string[]) => {
    setExpanded(nodeIds);
  };

  const renderTreeItems = (
    node: MyNode,
    nodeDisabled: boolean,
  ) => {
    return (
      <StyledTreeItemRoot
        key={node.id}
        nodeId={'' + node.id}
        label={
          <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', p: 0.5, pr: 0 }}>
            <Typography
              variant='body2'
            >
              {node.title}
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        }
        disabled={nodeDisabled}
        {...props.treeItemProps}
      >
        {Array.isArray(node.children)
          ? node.children.map((node) => renderTreeItems(node, nodeDisabled))
          : null}
      </StyledTreeItemRoot>
    );
  };

  return (
    <TreeView
      expanded={expanded}
      selected={props.selectedNodeId}
      onNodeSelect={(_event: React.SyntheticEvent, nodeId: string) => {
        props.onSelect(nodeId);
      }}
      onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
      {...props.treeViewProps}
    >
      {props.tree.map((item) =>
        renderTreeItems(item, props.treeDisabled ?? false),
      )}
    </TreeView>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a useEffect listening for the change of disable prop and calling a forceUpdate function like this:

```
  const forceUpdate = React.useReducer(() => ({}), {})[1] as () => void; 

  useEffect(() => {
    forceUpdate();
  }, [forceUpdate, props.treeDisabled]);
```

Edit:
Although the first solution worked, I changed to adding the prop, which tells the tree to be disabled or not, to the key prop in the tree.

```
 <TreeView
  key={String(props.treeDisabled)}
  expanded={expanded}
  selected={props.selectedNodeId}
  onNodeSelect={(_event: React.SyntheticEvent, nodeId: string) => {
    props.onSelect(nodeId);
  }}
  onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
    {...props.treeViewProps}
  >
    {props.tree.map((item) =>
        renderTreeItems(item, props.treeDisabled ?? false),
    )}
</TreeView>
```